# commenting java code within scriptlet tag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, exception

I have the below jsp file in which there is a java code inside the scriplet. Within that scriplet i want to comment a piece of code , which I have commented in the below way as shown. In the updated code also at the end I have added a comment mentioning the bug no., now can you please advise whether this is the correct way to comment in JSP?

```
<%
    try {
        String FunctionName = "abc_message";
 //c = eBean.getByID(Integer.parseInt(abcId));
 c = eBean.getByID(Long.parseLong(abcId)); // BugId:29
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advised to keep commented out **code** in java class. JSP will be converted to java class only. You can add comments to make your code readable and understandable but **commented out code** should not be there. You can use version control tool like **SVN/Git**, if you want to keep track of bugs or any changes and to have versions of your code.

Comment: Thanks will remove that commented code also but my point is that the way i commented using '//' , is it allowed inside scriptlet , please advise

Comment: Code inside a scriptlet is java code so you can add comments as you add in class either `// COMMENT` or  `/* BLOCK COMMENTS */`.